# add ImageView in a View?

Tags: android, view, imageview

I want to add an ImageView dynamically or from an xml into a class which extends View.....
pleas help
this is my code ...but it doesn't show any image...
first class

```
public class Draw extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               drawView = new DrawView(this, null);
         setContentView(drawView);

    }
}
```

2nd class

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    Path path;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
    ImageView imageView;
 // image img=new image();

    private ArrayList<Path> graphics = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_id); /* Load your ImageView 
        based on your id from your XML file */
        iv.setImageDrawable(
        this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimageinyourdrawablefolder)
        );

      //  img.showImage(); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        System.out.println("onDraw"+graphics);
        for (Path path : graphics) {
            //canvas.drawPoint(graphic.x, graphic.y, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        // return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            path = new Path();
            System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN");
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            graphics.add(path);
             System.out.println("ACTION_MOVE");
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            graphics.add(path);

            }

       invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main" 
    >

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/image_id"
  />
</LinearLayout >
```

I am trying with the above code and it crashes in the emulator. Is there any syntax error or something that I have made mistake. Please help.

Comment: Sorry that we can't give you a good answer but your question and your code looks so confused that you may want to read a little bit more and do some of the simple tutorials. You don't want to extend any of the View classes at the moment and you have to add the imageview to some kind of layout that is shown on the screen. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29 You also don't neet to load the drawable just provide a drawable resource to the imageview.

Comment: Janusz is correct, you don't need to load the ImageView itself, it's enough to add a resource in your XML file, like I described below.

Comment: You can edit your own questions, you know.